# perl Text::CSV parsing

Tags: perl

I have a very bizarre (at least to me!) situation where a csv file I was parsing in perl was working great for weeks, but now all the sudden it won't parse correctly.

Relevant information:

1. The file is an extract from Salesforce.com that is updated weekly
2. The file is comma separated with no escape characters, as far as I can tell 3) I've played a bit with the `new` attributes, but still no luck, really
3. Today's file is about 16 lines (incl header and some extraneous lines at the bottom that I don't care about). So there are 7 lines of data I want to evaluate.

My perl code is below. I think it's solid, but maybe there is a setting I am missing as the file is being read as 1 long string, as when I use `print $.` and `print $_` I only get 1 result that is the entire file in 1 line. Then of course, that line won't parse (and the error message is cryptic).

**Update:**

I have discovered the problem is with the way the file was generated from SFDC. The file has `CR` as the `End of Line`. I downloaded today's file and it has `CR` and `LF` for `End of Line`. It processes perfectly. I then went to de-sensitize yesterday's file to post and as I edited it, i got both the carriage return and line feed as EOL elements. Go figure!

For some reason the `TEXT::CSV` does not like to parse the file with only carriage returns as the EOL. Although not reflected in the code below, I have tried every possible setting for the `EOL` attribute in `TEXT::CSV->new()` method.

I am leaving the question open as it could be useful to know how to parse files with only carriage returns as EOL feeds.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Text::CSV;

my $datadump = "//myServer/WeeklyReport/data_dump.csv";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => ',', binary => 1});
open (CSV, "<", $datadump) or die $!;

while (<CSV>) {
    chomp $_;
    next if ($. == 1); # skip first line (contains headers)
    if ($csv->parse($_)) { # parse the line ...
        my @fields = $csv->fields(); 
        my $opp_owner = $fields[8];
        chomp $opp_owner;
        $owner_hash{$opp_owner} = "ignore"; # load into hash to delete duplicates
    } else { # if the line won't parse, return error
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $err";
    }
}

close CSV;
```

Comment: Maybe the new input file has different line endings than the old input.

Comment: @mob -> I was thinking about that ... but how can I tell?

Comment: On linux/unix, run `od -c filename`. I don't know the helpful tool for Windows, but if you open the file in Notepad and it doesn't look right, then it means you don't have Windows (`\r\n`) line endings.

Comment: @mob -> yes, it's one big line in Notepad (I was playing with that earlier). It opens fine in XL and Notepad++, but notepad it's one big line.... I am trying something now, but is there a way around it?

Comment: It sounds like you've got Unix line endings this week.  According to the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) pages, consider: `my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, eol => "\n" });`  The example I filched said `$/` instead of `"\n"`, but you seem to need newlines as the end-of-line character.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -> many thanks for the response, but i've tried every possible option under the eol attribute that is supported, all to no avail. There are not many things I have found desirable about Salesforce.com, and this certainly isn't adding to it.

Comment: You can always just remove all line endings, e.g. `s/[\r\n]+$//g`.

Comment: You really ought to post the file.

Comment: @paddy - good idea. I thought I would do that if an answer couldn't be found fast. I'll have to edit out some sensitive information, but will post tomorrow.

Comment: As others said, post some of the data, or a hex dump (or octal dump) of the first couple of lines; desensitize it, of course, but also make sure your script fails on the dumped data in the same way (there's no point in us trying to debug what works anyway).  The `Text::CSV` page says use '`binary => 1`' but you're not showing that.  I've not tried out your script on any data yet, but I didn't see any immediate horrors (other than the binary issue).

Comment: No issues with the Perl that I see at a glance. What do you see in Notepad++ when you view the file and turn on View->Show Symbol->Show End of Line?  If it is showing only line feeds as others suggest, try replacing "\n" with "\r\n" and then running it through your original functional script.  Alternatively, using the Notepad++ plug-in Compare with an old working file and this new problem file may reveal the source of the problem.

Comment: @uptownnickbrown -> Thanks for this advice. This got me to the source of the issue. I am editing my question now to reflect my findings.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your revised question is that there's no option to change the newline character. You can see all the Text::CSV options at [http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV](http://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV) . The verbatim option there seemed relevant, so I had a Google for you, but couldn't find anything. (Among other things "intitle:text intitle:csv intitle:verbatim" yielded no results.)